# Laravel error in artisan when using composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I've been googling for this for a time now. Hopefully you can help me.

I have a server hosted on 1and1 and I am using laravel. When I want to install or update a package via composer (`php composer.phar update`) I have this error:

> **Warning**:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in **/htdocs/artisan** on line **31**
>   
>   **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in **/htdocs/artisan** on line **31**

The line in artisan is:

> $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

**Overview of versions**
php -v `PHP 5.5.32 (cli) (built: Feb 15 2016 16:13:44)`
php artisan -V `Laravel Framework version 5.2.22`

So I am using a higher version as required by laravel (PHP >= 5.5.9) but I still get these errors

Comment: My suggestion: type `which php` from your terminal and change all entries in your `composer.json` `scripts` entries (e.g. `post-install-cmd`) to reference the absolute path your CLI uses to reach PHP. e.g. `/usr/bin/php5/php artisan optimize` vs just `php artisan optimize`. I suspect you have multiple versions of PHP installed, your CLI uses 5.3+ and for whatever reason composer is not using that version.

Comment: Well 1and1 has a lot of php versions installed but I configured the server for version 5.5.32. Running `php artisan clear-compiled` or `/usr/bin/php5.5-cli artisan clear-compiled` does not matter. works perfectly fine. but when calling `/usr/bin/php5.5-cli composer.phar update` artisan throws `Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error`

Comment: you may have configured CLI and apache to, but obviously whatever version is running during composer update doesn't support namespaces